# Storage of account password on keychain iOS to enable TouchID login

Tags: ios, security, mobile, keychain, password-encryption

Currently in the middle of a rather long-winded process of deciding upon the use of TouchID within an application being developed due, to security concerns, and wondered if anyone had any advice?

The idea from a product point of view is that a user can register with the application with a username/password (bog-standard flow in case of fall back for devices with no touch id) and then at a later date, if turned on via in-app preferences, use the TouchID system to 'login' to the application instead of typing a username/password again.

My concern is that this somehow means we have to store something on the device (retrievable upon successful touch) which can then authenticate the user and allow them access to the API (via JWT token, but probably doesn't matter).

This goes against almost everything I have ever read and been involved in with regards to mobile application development, which is storing anything sensitive on the client device is opening yourself up to an attack vector.

Yet - many applications already do this, so I am wondering what a typical process for enabling such a feature would be?

The app is sensitive by nature, has some personal information management which would be bad if leaked, if this makes a difference to the approach!

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is always an attack vector, the question is it within your defined security model. First you must define the attacker and their capabilities (script-kiddie to well funded government). Define the value of what is being protected in $ to the user, your liability $, reputation cost and to the attacker. Then you can define the security. On iOS the safest place to to put sensitive data in the keychain. If the value is above $10K, hire a security domain expert, I have. The weakest link is usually the server, how good the authentication is and the number of administrators, current and past.

Comment: You can store the data in the keychain and use TouchID to access it. You can set an option on the keychain item so that it becomes inaccessible if new fingers are enrolled in TouchID. You would typically just store the user id/password in the keychain so you don't need to change your standard authentication with your server. An attacker is far more likely to breach your server than the device keychain.

Comment: The application would have financial elements to it - so there is inherent risk. I am basically trying to ascertain the merits of being able to implement TouchID or not. Interesting that the assumption is the keychain is secure though, if that is genuinely the case then maybe it is not such an issue as I initially thought.

Comment: @Paulw11 - is there an example of the keychain item setting (for the new fingerprints functionality mentioned) in the docs somewhere? Can't seem to find anything!